# AJAX Request to MVC Controller with DataTable as Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to pass `DataTable` as Parameter to Controller. The `data` is always null when i use the below code.

**Object**

```
public class Notification
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public DataTable Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateNotification(Notification data)
{
   if(data == null)
   {
        //data is always null here
   }
}
```

**Request through POSTMAN**

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
    UserId: 1,
    Profiles: [1,2]
}
```

When i remove `Profiles`, it is working fine. But on having the parameter the `data` is always null. Whats an issue with it?

Comment: This isn't going to work because the model binder doesn't know what to do with a DataTable object. If you really want to do this thing, then you'll have to write yourself a custom model binder.

Comment: @Yellowfog, can u give some idea on that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knocked up something quickly which works if you *really* want the DataTable, but it's not the best quality code:

This wires up the new model binder in the method:

```
public ActionResult UpdateNotification([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))] Notification data)
{
    ....
}
```

specified here

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{

     protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "Profiles")
        {
            string vals = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Profiles[]"];
            Notification notificiation = (Notification)bindingContext.Model;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
            notificiation.Profiles = table;
            foreach (string strId in vals.Split(",".ToCharArray()))
            {
                int intId;
                if (int.TryParse(strId, out intId))
                {
                    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                    dr[0] = intId;
                    table.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }

        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your DataTable to a array which can be known from model binder.
Sample:

```
public class Notification
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public int[,] Profiles { get; set; }
}

Content-Type: application/json
{
    UserId: 1,
    Profiles: [[1,2]]
}
```